# AngularJS how to use $watch variables with $http?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to change a variable by using a filter. Which looks like this.

```
<select ng-init="inputStatus='ALL'" ng-model="inputStatus">
  <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
  <option value="NEW">NEW</option>
  <option value="RENEW">RENEW</option>
  <option value="FINISHED">FINISHED</option>
  <option value="FAILED">FAILED</option>
</select>
```

As you can see each time I select a new option the variable will change.

This is my $watch function.

```
var testValue = '';

$scope.$watch('inputStatus', function(val) {

  if (val) {
   testValue = val;
  }
}, true);

console.log(testValue);
```

I need to use testValue here in order to filter through the data.

```
$http.get("/api/v1/websites/?limit=" + $scope.main.limit + "&offset=" + $scope.main.offset + "&status=" + testValue)
then(function successCallback(result) {
    $scope.websites = result.data.results;
});
```

How can I do that?

Comment: are the `$watch` call and the `$http` call in different controllers/scopes?

Comment: No, they are in the same controller.

Comment: I think you need to describe [what you are trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) instead. Your `<select>` can have `ng-change="doSomething(inputStatus)"` . It also depends on where `testValue` is located and if `$http` can reach it (otherwise consider using Service/Factory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$watch`, use the [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive:

```
<select ng-init="inputStatus='ALL'" ng-model="inputStatus"
        ng-change="updateWebsite(inputStatus)">
  <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
  <option value="NEW">NEW</option>
  <option value="RENEW">RENEW</option>
  <option value="FINISHED">FINISHED</option>
  <option value="FAILED">FAILED</option>
</select>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.updateWebsites = updateWebsites;

function updateWebsites(status) {
    var url = "/api/v1/websites";
    var params = { limit: $scope.main.limit,
                   offset: $scope.main.offset,
                   status: status };

    var config = { params: params };

    $http.get(url, config)
      .then(function successHandler(response) {
         $scope.websites = response.data.results;
    }).catch(function errorHandler(response) {
         console.log("ERROR", response.status)
    });
}
```